# Google OAuth: "invalid_grant" still a thing

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I've been stuck for hours getting the Google OAuth2 flow going in my Node/Express application. The basics are fairly straight-forward:

1. Create Google application credentials
2. Redirect users to consent screen
3. Receive a `code` value
4. Exchange `code` for `access_token` and `refresh_token`
5. Store `refresh_token` for the future

For whatever reason, I cannot pass Step 4 above and always get the following response:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "description": "Bad Request"
}
```

There are a ton of other solutions asking about the above, and no solution has yet worked for me:

- Don't use the same `code` regardless of result
- Wait a while after adding new Authorized Redirect URIs
- Include *http://localhost:3000* as an Authorized Redirect URI
- Include all variants with/without protocol, port, trailing-slash
- Set `access_type` to *offline* previously if needed (and it is)
- Use Request instead of Axios
- Include a null `scope` parameter like the OAuth Playground
- Encode parameters using Querystring
- Confirm `application/x-www-urlencoded` is the Content-Type
- Log out of all Google accounts when retrying
- Be aware of Google's token creation limit

With the above stated, here's the specifics of my plight:

**Host**: http://localhost:3000

**Callback #1**: http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback (*where `code` is sent and exchange action below is run*)

**Callback #2**: http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callbacktwo (*where `access_token` and `refresh_token` should be returned*)

**Exchange Action**: Adjusted for Request module

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: {
      'code': req.query.code,
      'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callbacktwo',
      'client_id': '***.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'client_secret': '***',
      'scope': null,
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
    }
}
```

**Authorized Redirect URIs**: Visible in Application > Credentials > OAuth 2.0 client IDs

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DJ8w.png)

---

All-in-all, I'm stuck. There's either something fundamentally wrong with my setup/approach or I'm the first developer encountering this bug (the latter can't be true). Can pay for assistance too.

Answer (score 1):

In a shocking turn of events, I **resolved** this within minutes of posting above with the changes below:

---

**Change #1**

> Added 'http://127.0.0.1' variants to my Authorized Redirect URIs list

Since '127.0.0.1' equates to 'localhost', thought I'd give it a try. Read this elsewhere.

---

**Change #2**

> Changed the Exchange Action's `redirect_uri` to Callback #1, which is where the `code` was sent.

I thought "what if Google isn't liking the `redirect URI` not being where it sent the `code`?".

---

**Change #3**

> Removed the Exchange Action's `scope` parameter

Though it's clearly visible in the OAuth Playground, it's not in the documentation.

---

And the result? Received the object I've been seeking for hours and hours:

```
{
   "access_token": "****",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "refresh_token": "***",
   "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "id_token": "*****"
}
```

*Disclaimer: This does not mean the above will work for you, but it did for me and I'll take it.*